# OpenFileDialog - Speed issue/hide dialog immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, openfiledialog

Hello im having trouble with file dialog

Standard code, but it's freezing while selecting large files (600MB+ *xls* file that i need to first reformat to xlsb, then stream data from, but that is not important here).

What i wanted to achieve is to hide dialog when ***Open*** button is clicked, so that i could display ***Loading Message***.

Yet im not sure how can i achieve that. Can i somehow subscribe to ***Open*** button?

```
OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog() { DereferenceLinks = false };

openFile.Title = "Select Supplier List";
openFile.Filter = "Excel files (*.*xls*)|*.*xls*";

try
{
    if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true) 
    {
        /* Takes long time to go after selection */
        ViewModel.ReportPath = openFile.FileName;
        ViewModel.FileTrueName = Path.GetFileName(ViewModel.ReportPath);
    }
}
catch
{
    ViewModel.ReportPath = null;
    ViewModel.FileTrueName = null;
}
```

Comment: **Exactly** which `OpenFileDialog` are you using?

Comment: `OpenFileDialog` hosts an instance of WIndows' built-in shell browser UI (just like `explorer.exe`) which includes all shell-extensions, including Microsoft (and others)' special file handlers; it's likely that one of those extensions is the cause of the freeze, but unfortunately I don't believe it's possible to disable all shell-extensions in `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is `openFile.ShowDialog()` and not `ReportPath` or `FileTrueName`  setters  ? Maybe you have some `OnReportPathChanged` code which takes long time

Comment: @Dai Win32. Selvin - commented them out, same issue.
Im starting to feel that i might be limited tow riting my own FileDialog, which is not something im eager to do as it's gonna take a lot of time.

Comment: @KrzysztofMastalerz "`Win32`" does not adequately narrow-down which library/implementation you're using.

Comment: @Dai Im not sure what do you mean, would this be sufficitent? - Assembly PresentationFramework, Version=6.0.2.0 for Microsoft.Win32

Comment: I believe that this is the documentation: [How to open a common dialog box (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/windows/how-to-open-common-system-dialog-box?view=netdesktop-6.0) and [OpenFileDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Comment: That's not the correct value for `Filter`. Try `openFile.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls";` or `openFile.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx";`

Comment: @user9938 I want a wildcard for all excel files *xls*, *xlsm*, *xlsx*, *xlsb*, thats why i used `*.*xls*`, although i can see i took one star too many :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping code with task, helped :)
Some changes happened during searching for answer, based on comments.

```
Task.Run(() => 
{
    OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFile.Title = "Select Supplier List";
    openFile.Filter = "Excel Files(*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsb; *.xlsm)| *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsb; *.xlsm";
    try
    {
        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            ViewModel.ReportPath = openFile.FileName;
            ViewModel.FileTrueName = Path.GetFileName(ViewModel.ReportPath);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewModel.ReportPath = null;
        ViewModel.FileTrueName = null;
    }
});
```